# React 18 - Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element | DocumentFragment'

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to practice React 18 and initially i got the deprecation warning and i have made the changes with **createRoot**. now i am facing an error stating

TS2345: Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element | DocumentFragment'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element | DocumentFragment'.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")); // error: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element | DocumentFragment'
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Have you tried to put a Fragment around React.StrictMode ?  I think React.StrictMode has a union type of HTMLElement | null and that's not accepted as the most external JSX Element.

Answer (score 49):

The issue here is that the return type of the document.getElementById method is HTMLElement | null.
But on the other hand, the expected parameter type of the **createRoot** method is Element | DocumentFragment, so there is a mismatch between the provided argument type and the expected parameter type.

The right way to do is either by giving type definition of Element or using an **!**

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as Element);
```

or

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!);
```

Comment: If you use `@typescript-eslint` you should use the first suggestion or a variant of it. The second suggestion results in a "Forbidden non-null assertion".

Comment: if you use eslint ESLint: Parsing error: Unexpected token as :)